# “Print page” button does not print

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to put a “print page” button in an HTML page. It looks great and clicks but will not print. I get 3 errors in the js file. 
They all say document is undefined

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
}())

var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var printPage = function() {
  window.print();
}

window.onload = function() {
  $("printButton").onclick = printPage;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="printButton" value="Print Page">
```

html

```
<head>
       <script src="printPage.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>  
        <input type="button" id="printButton" value="Print Page">
<body>
```

Comment: We're definitely going to need some HTML with that

Comment: At the very least you need a `<input type="button" id="printButton"/>` in your HTML. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: This is what I put in the header of the HTML file....                                                <script src="printPage.js"></script>

Comment: I think the problem is that when you do `$("printButton")` you forgot to add the `#` symbol before `"printButton"` so it should be `$("#printButton")`

Comment: @Ameer he's not mentioning jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
}())

var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var printPage = function() {
  window.print();
}

window.onload = function() {
  $("printButton").onclick = printPage;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="printButton" value="Print Page">
```

This snippet certainly run. So you must have a broken JS somewhere that break your code in the middle. Like including a jQuery lib will override your `$`.
We would need more information. Try to do some debugging to see if your code reach that function.

At very least, try simply `console.log($("printButton"))` to see if it found the element. If the element is loaded using Ajax, then it's a another story.